# Unable to cover to test class for below trigger

Tags: unit-test, failing-tests, contentversion, contentdocument

I have written trigger and a test class for my content version

**Handler**

```
public class handlerClassContentVersion{
    public set<string>prodNames = new set<string>();
    public set<string>contentid = new set<string>();
    public list<Product2>proList = new list<Product2>();
    public list<File_Entries__c>entList = new list<File_Entries__c>();
    public map<id,id>fileEntryMap = new map<id,id>();

    public void onAfterInsert(list<ContentVersion>conList){
        for(ContentVersion cov:conList){//capturing trigger.new 
            prodNames.add(cov.Product__c); 
            contentid.add(cov.ContentDocumentId);
        }

        proList = [select id,name from Product2 where name IN :prodNames];

        List<File_Entries__c> lstFileEntries = [select id,Product__c,File_ID__c from File_Entries__c where File_ID__c IN: contentid];//querying existing file entries records
        for(File_Entries__c lst:lstFileEntries){
            fileEntryMap.put(lst.File_ID__c,lst.id);//mapping contentdocument id and file id
        }
        for(ContentVersion cov:conList){
            for(Product2 pro : proList){
                if(lstFileEntries.size()>0){//updatinf gor existing records
                    if(fileEntryMap!=null && fileEntryMap.get(cov.ContentDocumentId)!=null){
                        File_Entries__c fe = new File_Entries__c(id=fileEntryMap.get(cov.ContentDocumentId));
                        fe.Product__c = pro.id;
                        fe.File_ID__c = cov.ContentDocumentId;
                        entList.add(fe);
                        system.debug('===entList==='+entList);

                    try{
                        update entList;     
                    }
                    catch(Exception e){
                    }
                }   
            }       
                    else{
                      system.debug('==else==');
                      File_Entries__c fe = new File_Entries__c();//creating new records
                      fe.Product__c = pro.id;
                      fe.File_ID__c = cov.ContentDocumentId;
                      entList.add(fe);
                    try{
                        insert entList;
                    }
                    catch(Exception e){
                    }
               } 
           }     
        }
    }
}
```

**Test**

```
@isTest
public class TesthandlerClassContentVersion{
    static testMethod void contentDoc() {
    list<ContentVersion>conlist = new list<ContentVersion>();

     //ContentDocument cd = [SELECT Id FROM ContentDocument ];


     ContentVersion cv = new ContentVersion();
     //cv.ContentDocumentId = '069M0000000Tpig';
     cv.Brand__c ='Heil';
     cv.Product_Category__c='Front Loader';
     cv.Product__c ='Half-Pack';
     cv.Document_Type__c = 'Generic Forms';
     cv.ContentURL='http://www.google.com/';
     cv.Title ='con';
     conlist.add(cv);
     insert cv;

     //ContentVersion cv = new ContentVersion();
     //cv.ContentDocumentId = '069M0000000Tpig';
     cv.Brand__c ='Heil';
     cv.Product_Category__c='Front Loader';
     cv.Product__c ='Half-Pack Freedom';
     cv.Document_Type__c = 'Generic Forms';
     cv.ContentURL='http://www.google.com/';
     cv.Title ='con';
     conlist.add(cv);
     update cv;

     handlerClassContentVersion handler = new handlerClassContentVersion();
     handler.onAfterInsert(conlist);
    }
}
```

I am not able to insert the content document and hence am not able to create a relationship between the content version  and the content document in my test class. I am getting a NULL Pointer exception at the line `handler.onAfterInsert(conlist);`.Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, `ContentDocument` is automatically inserted by SFDC when you insert a `ContentVersion`. This is covered in the [SFDC Objects doc](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_contentdocument.htm)

You can discover the `ContentDocument` by doing:

```
ContentVersion cv = new ContentVersion(title='foo', contentUrl='http:///www.foor.bar');
insert cv;
ContentVersion cvRes = [select id, ContentDocument.id, ContentDocument.title 
                         from ContentVersion where id= :cv.id];
ContentDocument cd = cv.ContentDocument;
```

Debug output:

```
ContentDocument=ContentDocument:{Id=06940000001sEpHAAU, Title=foo}
ContentVersion=ContentVersion:{Id=06840000002udVdAAI, ContentDocumentId=06940000001sEpHAAU}
```

Secondly, your testmethod is updating the inserted `ContentVersion` and then adding it again to the list `conList`. Updating a `ContentVersion` does not create a new version, it simply edits the existing version.

Thirdly, your handler line:

```
contentid.add(cov.ContentDocumentId);
```

will add null to `contentId` as you need to requery for `ContentDocumentId` before invoking your handler as `conList` (and by inference any `cv` element) will not have `ContentDocumentId` set.  Hence null pointer exception.

You can think of `ContentDocumentId` as like a fomula field or auto-number field on an inserted sobject. The value is not known to the apex code until you requery the`ContentVersion`.